# Partial derivates check $wx_{id}$ versus ($wx_{id}^2$ + $wx_{id}^3$)? (w.r.t w)

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I'm trying to work on a problem (to do with neural networks), but my maths background is VERY limited and I was wondering whether someone could confirm what the general difference of computing the partial derivatives (with respect to w) of the two forms that I mention below,

I thought that this one [image: this one] would be $x_{id}$,

and [image: this one] would be $2x_{id}$ + $3x_{id}^2$?

I feel like I might have gotten the wrong idea and that these wouldn't be this simple to generalise.

Comment: Information that is vital to understanding your question should not be included as an image unless it is completely unavoidable.

Comment: The first equation when differentiated with respect to $w_i$ (NOT $w$) is $x_{id}$ since everything else is zero. Same for the second part. If you want to differentiate w.r.t $w$ (which is a vector) you can only compute gradients.